# Influxdb 2.0 Flux - How to return 0 instead null

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I want to count amount of values that are greater than specific value.
Data:

[image]

```
from(bucket: "bucket name")
    |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._value > 35)
    |> count()
```

If there are no values in the processing data range that are greater the specified value than the influx returns nothing (no data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution with a little trick...
Instead of `filter()` and `count()` - need to use `map()` and `sum()`

```
from(bucket: "bucket name")
     |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
     |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with _value: if r._value 35 then 1 else 0 }))
     |> sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Failing: InfluxDB2 null as zero (float())

Issues appeared with float values ,

where a virtual instance not running for a (missing) timeframe

appeared as constantly-cpu-consuming...

Influxdb connects series without 0 ,here a cpu graph with missing timeframes
[image: Influxdb connects series without 0 ,here a cpu graph with missing timeframes]

- `fill()` only works on integers,
- non-existing datapoints can't be if-catched by value (...)
- `aggregateWindow()` finally helped

### Solution: InfluxDB2 null as zero (float())

```
from(bucket: "sys")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "docker_cpu_percent" )
//  |> window(every: 5m, period: 5m, createEmpty: true)
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 5m, fn: mean, createEmpty: true)
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({
      r with
      _value: if exists r._value then float(v: r._value) * 1.0  else 0.0
    })
  )
```

[image: Proper resonse from influx with null as 0 float() when using aggregateWindow()]

### Resources

You might refer to

- the [InfluxDB aggregateWindow() documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/flux/window-aggregate/)
- [and for the if and map() usage in the query logic documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/flux/conditional-logic/)
- [the InfluxDB fill() function](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/fill/#parameters)